# Install two instance of wampserver on same pc

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have installed two instance of wampserver on same windows pc, one in `C:\wamp` path and another in `D:\wamp` path. 
Now when i start wamp server manager from `c:\wamp\wampmanager`, apache and mysql start from `d:\wamp` path! and i cannot see my first wamp server databeses. please help me...

Comment: Thats because you cannot install 2 instances of WAMPServer on the same PC. The second install will override the first install. Its not a WAMPServer limitation, its an Apache/MySQL limitation.

Comment: Why do you want 2 installs?

Comment: any way to see only the c:\wamp one? i need databases on that server :(

Comment: I was think this two versions will be separate completely!

Comment: You do realise that you can have more than one version of Apache and/or MySQL and/or PHP within a single instance of WAMPServer dont you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get back to the first install, the one on your C: drive, you can do this.

Launch the current WAMPServer, the one looking at the D: install

Using the wampmanager menus do

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Remove Service
(right click)wampmanager -> exit
```

Now delete the WAMPServer desktop icon, and/or the one in your start menu.

Make a new desktop icon from C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe

Launch WAMPServer from this new desktop icon

Using the wampmanager menus do

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
wait 10 second
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
wait 10 second
wampmanager -> Start all service
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved me :)