# Copied WAMP from old Windows 10 install and all URLs get "Not Found"

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I didn't want to have to setup SSL, my extensions, timeout settings, upload file sizes and all that junk again so I installed WAMP, Visual Studio, then deleted the /wamp dir and copied my old WAMP dir over, symlink files and all.

WAMP starts up fine, goes green but any URL I try at localhost is like;

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /football-colours/ was not found on this server.

Same PHP.ini as before, same .conf files - files are on c:\wamp on both installs. No logs are being generated. Same OS too.

Comment: By `Visual Studio` do you actually mean ALL the require MSVC Runtime libraries or did you actually install `Visual Studio`

Comment: Did you install the exact same version of WAMPServer on the new machine as was on the old machine?

Comment: And which version of WAMPServer are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was file not found because even though I was launch WAMPmanager.exe in the old dir, it was launching the server in the new install location.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922939/5790980 sorted it.